# Property is not reactive in vue-class-component

Tags: vue.js

I have made two components which share one object as:

```
UnitData: {
  FirstName: null,
  LastName: null,
  Department: null,
  OvertimeRate: null,
}
```

First Component have two fields which bind to first two properties of the above `UnitData` object and 2nd component's two fields bind to last two fields. The components are:

```
 <employee-basic-info-form-component
  :unit-data="UnitData"
  @next="Step = 2; UnitData = $event"
/>
 <employee-job-info-form-component
  :unit-data="UnitData"
  @next="Step = 3; UnitData = $event"
  @back="Step = 1"
/>
```

So, in my `employee-basic-info-form-component.vue`, I have this code:

```
@Component({
  props: {
    unitData: Object
  },
})
export default class EmployeeBasicInfoFormComponent extends Vue {
  public UnitData = this.unitData;
}
```

And the fields are working fine and on sending the form I am calling a `next()` function which contains `this.$emit('next', this.UnitData);`.

`UnitData` is updating after `@next="Step = 2; UnitData = $event"`, but the 2nd component as `employee-job-info-form-component.vue` doesn't updating the `UnitData` value, any suggestions?

So, in my `employee-job-info-form-component.vue`, I have this code:

```
@Component({
  props: {
    unitData: Object
  },
})
export default class EmployeeJobInfoFormComponent extends Vue {
  public UnitData = this.unitData; //<-- this is not updating
}
```